Mega-menu closing itself during interaction
I'm currently working on implementing a mega-menu with complex logic for a website project. The mega-menu consists of multiple levels of nested menus, and I'm facing challenges in ensuring stable and safe functionality. Below is an overview of the logic I'm trying to implement:
Mega-Menu Logic Overview:
The mega-menu, which acts as the sub-menu for 'uslugi', requires a sophisticated logic implementation. The code must prioritize stability and security.

Implementation Guidelines:
Responsive Design:

The mega-menu logic should only be active on desktop screens wider than 1024px. It should be completely disabled on screens below this width.
Modern JavaScript Standards:

Implement the logic using contemporary JavaScript standards to ensure compatibility and efficiency.
HTML Structure Selector:
Selector: n-nav__i--0 > n-nav__link--0 > menu-arrow

Level Zero Menus:
Opening the Menu:
Types of Level Zero Elements:
z Type: Contains 'sub-menu-uslugi' within. Here, clicking on the entire 'n-nav__i--0' element should toggle activation for 'n-nav__link--0'. It's not limited to just the 'menu-arrow'.
x Type: Contains 'menu-item-has-children' as a classname. In this case, the menu should open using 'menu-arrow', and clicking on 'n-nav__link--0' should redirect the user.
Activation:
Clicking on 'n-nav__i--0' or 'menu-arrow' inside 'n-nav__i--0' activates the menu.
Activation via 'menu-arrow' should also be possible.
Deactivation:
For 'z Type': Clicking again on 'n-nav__i--0'.
For 'x Type': Clicking again on the 'menu-arrow'.
Clicking outside the mega-menu ('sub-menu-uslugi').
Level One Menus:
Activation Logic:
While inside 'sub-menu-uslugi', the menu should remain open.
Clicking on 'n-nav__i--1' should keep the level zero active.
Activate 'n-nav__link--1' when clicking on 'n-nav__i--1' with 'menu-item-has-children'.
Otherwise, redirect to 'n-nav__link--1'.
Chunk Activation: The parent chunk of 'n-nav__i--1' should become active, while other chunks must hide.
Level Two Menu:
Display Logic:
Display elements associated with 'n-nav__link--1'.
Clicking on '.menu-btn' within 'n-nav__link-icon' should:
Deactivate the chunk.
Make hidden chunks visible by removing the hidden state.
Deactivate 'n-nav__link--1' by removing the active state.
Additional Logic:
Only one level-zero sub-menu should be active at a time.
Close the menu when interacting outside 'sub-menu-uslugi' (mega-menu).
Active states disappear upon interacting outside the menu while it's active, returning to normal.

I've attempted to implement this logic using modern JavaScript standards, but I'm encountering issues with stability and proper functionality. Here's what I've tried so far:
(() => {
    const toggleActive = (el) => el.classList.toggle('active');
    const activateChunk = (chunk) => {
        document.querySelectorAll('.chunk').forEach((el) => {
            const isActive = el === chunk;
            el.classList.toggle('active', isActive);
            el.hidden = !isActive;
        });
    };
    const resetDesktopStates = () => {
        document.querySelectorAll('.n-nav__link--0.active, .n-nav__link--1.active, .n-nav__i--1.active, .menu-btn.active, .chunk.active').forEach((el) => {
            el.classList.remove('active');
        });
    };
    const closeLevelZero = () => {
        document.querySelectorAll('.n-nav__link--0.active').forEach((link) => {
            link.classList.remove('active');
        });
    };
    const isInMenuStructure = (target) => {
        return target.closest('.n-nav__i--0') || target.closest('.n-nav__i--1') || target.closest('.sub-menu-uslugi');
    };
    const handleLevelZero = (e) => {
        const clicked = e.target.closest('.n-nav__i--0');
        if (!clicked) return;
        const hasSubMenu = clicked.querySelector('.sub-menu-uslugi');
        const hasChildren = clicked.classList.contains('menu-item-has-children');
        const isActive = clicked.querySelector('.n-nav__link--0').classList.contains('active');
        if ((hasSubMenu || hasChildren) && !isActive) {
            e.preventDefault();
            closeLevelZero();
            toggleActive(clicked.querySelector('.n-nav__link--0'));
        } else if ((hasSubMenu || hasChildren) && isActive) {
            e.preventDefault();
            closeLevelZero();
        } else if (hasChildren && clicked.querySelector('.menu-arrow')?.contains(e.target)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            closeLevelZero();
            toggleActive(clicked.querySelector('.n-nav__link--0'));
        } else if (!isInMenuStructure(e.target)) {
            closeLevelZero();
        }
    };
    const handleLevelOne = (e) => {
        const clicked = e.target.closest('.n-nav__i--1');
        if (!clicked) return;
        const hasChildren = clicked.classList.contains('menu-item-has-children');
        if (hasChildren) {
            toggleActive(clicked.querySelector('.n-nav__link--1'));
            activateChunk(clicked.closest('.chunk'));
            const levelZeroMenu = clicked.closest('.n-nav__i--0');
            if (levelZeroMenu) {
                toggleActive(levelZeroMenu.querySelector('.n-nav__link--0'));
            }
        } else {
            const link = clicked.querySelector('.n-nav__link--1');
            if (link) {
                e.preventDefault();
                window.location.href = link.href;
            }
        }
    };
    const handleLevelTwo = (e) => {
        if (e.target.closest('.menu-btn')) {
            const clicked = e.target.closest('.n-nav__i--1');
            toggleActive(clicked.querySelector('.n-nav__link--1'));
            activateChunk(null);
        }
    };
    const handleResize = () => {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 1024) {
            resetDesktopStates();
            document.removeEventListener('click', handleLevelZero);
            document.removeEventListener('click', handleLevelOne);
            document.removeEventListener('click', handleLevelTwo);
        }
    };
    const isClickOutsideSubMenu = (event) => {
        const subMenu = document.querySelector('.sub-menu-uslugi');
        return subMenu && !subMenu.contains(event.target);
    };
    const handleOutsideClick = (event) => {
        if (isClickOutsideSubMenu(event)) {
            resetDesktopStates();
            document.removeEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick);
        }
    };
    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (window.innerWidth > 1024) {
            handleLevelZero(e);
            handleLevelOne(e);
            handleLevelTwo(e);
            if (!isInMenuStructure(e.target)) {
                document.addEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick);
            }
        }
    });
    resetDesktopStates();
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
})();

Despite my efforts, I'm still facing issues with certain functionalities not working as expected, especially regarding menu activation, deactivation, and handling of different menu types.
What I'm trying to achieve is that, when user clicks and interacting inside of the sub-menu-uslugi, the menu should stay opened, but I can't achieve that, is there any safer approaches to make it work as described?
Could someone please provide guidance on how to properly implement this complex mega-menu logic using modern JavaScript standards? Any insights, suggestions, or corrections to my current approach would be greatly appreciated.
